Connect Network traffic to my garage over a wireless bridge
I have a router (Netgear Orbi) with a 192.168.1.x subnet. I have a wireless Bridge (Trendnet) between my house and my Garage. The bridge is on a 192.168.10.x subnet. In the garage is another wireless Router (Belkin). The IP addresses on the bridge are 192.168.10.50 on the near end and 192.168.10.51 on the far end. The gateway is 192.168.10.1. In the garage, the Belkin router is using 192.168.0.x subnet. What I want to do is have the bridge connect my Orbi network with the internet through the bridge to the garage network and have wireless and wired connections there. What would be the simplest way to make this work?

Does it currently not work? From the description, it sounds like everything should be working already.

No, it's not working. The Orbi is a new router and it hasn't worked since then. I forgot to mention that I have a Netgear Nighthawk Router that sits between the Orbi and the Wireless bridge.
